# Does Mockito require Dexmaker when mocking Android applications?

Tags: java, android, maven, mockito, dexmaker

The documentation of the Mockito and Dexmaker projects does not seem to clearly state the relationship between the two, they only make mention of each other. If Dexmaker is required, which versions of Mockito and Dexmaker are compatible?, and is only the dexmaker-mockito artifact required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the latest version of mockito (at the moment 1.9.5), as seen in the main [documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html) [§28](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#28). Mockito offer a way to have a different bytecode engine, that dexmaker-mockito provide if it's on the same classpath. (Indeed the wiki is a bit outdated [there](http://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/wiki/Mockito) but it states you need both jars).

Hope that helps.

Comment: So does that mean you **need** dexmaker (both jars) for mockito to work?

Comment: @Ryan yes, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I got errors when I included both Mockito and DexMaker. In the end, this is what I added to gradle:

```
//compile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
compile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
compile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
```